# Javascript Media Query bug, it won't apply the code if the window is equal or smaller than "x" pixels, only on resize

Tags: javascript, html

So, I don't know whether something is missing from this script, or it's a bug, but..

I have a h1, if the window width is smaller than 350px, I want to change the `innerHTML`. Pretty basic, huh?

When **the screen size is already smaller than 350px** the script won't work! What can I do?

`HTML`

```
<h1 id="h1">Text</h1>
```

`javascript`

```
var h1 = document.getElementById("h1");
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 350px)');

function h1Text(){
 if(mediaQuery.matches){
   h1.innerHTML = ("Text 1");
  }
 else {
   h1.innerHTML = ("Text");
    }
  }

mediaQuery.addListener(h1Text);


 //Resize the document and make it smaller than 350px, then run again the fiddle
```

The fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/euy005gk/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `h1Text` manually after you set it as the listener.

```
mediaQuery.addListener(h1Text);
h1Text();
```

As the name implies, `.addListener()` adds a function that will be called when the match state of the media query *changes*. It doesn't immediately execute the listener when you set it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Did not expect to be this easy. It's kind of hard for me to wrap my head around listeners/event listeners. Will be accepting your answer immediately.